# boostrap carousel on angular 4 project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to implement a boostrap carousel and the RouteModule of Angular 4.

If I reload the page the carousel works fine, but when I navegate inside the web using routerLink never cycle as expected.

I'm guessing that angular adds the html dynamically and doesn't trigger the js to make it start cycing images.

There is a way to reload that boostrap component on the load of the component, right?

The component that holds the carousel is "ProyectorZonaComponent" and here is app.module and the chunk of code that use to navigate

Appreciate ya!

app.module.ts

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'rosario', component: ProyectorZonaComponent, data: { title: 'Tv Rosario', zona: 'rosario' } },
  { path: 'lima', component: ProyectorZonaComponent, data: { title: 'Tv Lima', zona: 'lima' } },
  { path: 'bsas', component: ProyectorZonaComponent, data: { title: 'Tv Buenos Aires', zona: 'bsas' }},
  { path: 'neco', component: ProyectorZonaComponent, data: { title: 'Tv Necochea', zona: 'neco' }},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: 'Tv' } },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProyectorZonaComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule, // imports firebase/database, only needed for database features
    AngularFireAuthModule, // imports firebase/auth, only needed for auth features
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home.component.html

```
<ul>
  <li> <a routerLink="/rosario">Rosario</a></li>
   <li><a routerLink="/neco">Necochea, Bahia Blanca</a></li>
   <li><a routerLink="/lima">Lima, Las Palmas</a></li>
   <li><a routerLink="/bsas">Buenos Aires</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the app.module

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
 ...
providers: [
  {
    provide: LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy
  }
]
...
})
```

Comment: mmmm no changes, that add a # in my routes but still it doesnt work. maybe i added incorrectly. Thks!